# Why am I getting this error : Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 15]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to solve the following problem but I am getting an error.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score
import numpy as np

degrees = np.arange(0, 9)
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
for i in degrees:
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(i)
    x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly, y, random_state = 0)
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
    r2_train = linreg.r2_score(X_train, y_train)
    r2_test = linreg.r2_train(X_test, y_test)
```

Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 15]

Any reason why am I getting the said error.

Answer (score 1):

### Three errors in the code:

1. You need to **reshape** `x` into a **2D** **numpy** **array by** using `x.reshape(-1,1)`.
2. `linreg.r2_score` is **invalid**. Also, no need to use `r2_score`. **Just** **use** `linreg.score`. This will return the coefficient of determination **R^2** of the prediction ([reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score)).
3. `degree` r2_score be `0` so use `PolynomialFeatures(i+1)` inside the loop **except** if you really intend to use a 0 degree polynomial expansion. Keep in mind that if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].

---

Full working example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


degrees = np.arange(0, 9)
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
for i in degrees:
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(i+1)
    x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1,1))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly, y, random_state = 0)
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
    r2_train = linreg.score(X_train, y_train)
    r2_test = linreg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: your code still gives error because train_test_split is not imported and what do you mean by " degree r2_score be 0 " in 3rd point?

Answer (score 0):

You have not reshaped x. x should be of shape (n_samples, n_features). And linreg.r2_score is no more. I modified the code as following:

```
degrees = np.arange(0, 9)
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

for i in degrees:
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(i)
    x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly, y, random_state = 0)
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
    r2_train = linreg.score(X_train, y_train)
    r2_test = linreg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: `PolynomialFeatures(i)` in the first iteration `i=0` so this is super wrong and invalid. See my answer below for a correct solution

Comment: @seralouk PolynomialFeature(0) is not an error. It is regression with bias term only. and running smoothly on my PC.

Answer (score -1):

Your code have lots of mistakes and typos. It will be useful if you first practice some well known solved problem like iris, house price regression problem etc.

Correct code :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

degrees = np.arange(0, 9)
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

#### convert x into 2D matrix  #####
x= x.reshape(-1,1)

i=1   
for i in degrees:
  poly = PolynomialFeatures(i)
  x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly, y, random_state = 0)
  linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
  r2_train = r2_score(y_train,linreg.predict(X_train))
  r2_test = r2_score(y_test ,linreg.predict(X_test))

#### linreg.score(X_train, y_train) can also used to calculate r2_score
```

Comment: how is that different from my answer posted 22 min ago?

Comment: both answer is good. little writing difference not much change.